# Why is NSURLConnection.response.contentLength = NSURLResponseUnknownLength?

Tags: ios, wcf, iis-6, nsurlconnection

All of a sudden, out of the blue my app-users started reporting that the app crashes during login.

What's to blame?

- Nothing changed in the app, same version since Oct 2013.
- Server is a REST WCF service which was also unchanged since Oct 2013.
- This web service is hosted in IIS 6 - some Windows updates were
  applied recently.
- Yesterday I updated the app's provisioning profile's certificate,
  since it was about to expire, but surely THIS cannot affect installed
  apps? Can it?

Upon closer inspection, the app crashes with the following exception: **[NSConcreteMutableData initWithCapacity:]: absurd capacity: 4294967295, maximum size: 2147483648 bytes'**

This is due to **NSURLConnection.response.expectedContentLength** being equal to "**NSURLResponseUnknownLength**", but unfortunately I didn't foresee this and my app is unable to correctly initialize the NSData object, and then crashes.

To get my app back up and running TODAY, I can't rely on rolling out the new version which compensates for the above-mentioned issue.
It seems obvious that the issue is server side, probably the IIS server no longer sending the "Expected Content Length" in the header.

In IIS the virtual directory's settings seem unchanged.

Any ideas/advice?

**Some Code:**

```
TTURLConnection* ttConnection = (TTURLConnection*)connection;
ttConnection.response = response;
NSLog(@"%lld", response.expectedContentLength); // ***This prints -1
NSLog(@"%lld", response.expectedContentLength); // ***This prints 1127

ttConnection.responseData = [NSMutableData DataWithCapacity:response.expectedContentLength];
```

I still maintain that the issue is server side, but I don't see how...

Comment: I am officially freaked out. Doing a simple NSLog of the NSURLConnection.response, changes the expected content-length from unknown to an actual value... HOW CAN THIS BE? Let me know if I should paste some code.

Comment: Some more info, after doing some tests, it seems it's possible for the "content-length" in the HTTP header to be affected by the router the connection passes through. I'm currently waiting for IT to confirm if any changes was made to the router that coincides with the time the app started crashing.